# Alinear elementos en una tabla

Tags: html, css, table, position

Buen día. Necesito ayuda con esto:

Tengo una tabla a la cual dentro de sus `<td>` le puse elementos de párrafo (letra y número). Le aplique la propiedad `RELATIVE` y configuré su posicionamiento (el mismo para todos los `<p>` de los `<td>`.

El problema es que el resultado final me da algunas letras de los  que están "descentradas" con respecto a las letras de otros  (de arriba o de abajo), a pesar de que todas tienen la misma configuración. Lo mismo pasa con los números. Por ejemplo: E5 con C12 quedan desalineados, pero E14 con C21 ó E23 con C30 quedan bien alineados.

Les paso la tabla para que vean cómo queda:

```css
table {border: solid; width: 50%; margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 30px; text-align: center; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: white;}

td, th {border: solid; padding: 0; height: 45px; width:}

th {background-color: grey;}

td {  vertical-align: middle;}

.sinBordes td{ /* Nueva clase */
  border: none; /* Mismo estilo */
}

.letra{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: -15px;
    top: -4px;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: 700;
 }

 .numero{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
    top: 5px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: 
 }
```

```html
<table>
            <th colspan="7"><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">Farmacias de Turno</span><br>Noviembre 2022</th>
            <tr style="background-color: black; color: white;" class="sinBordes">
                <td>D</td>
                <td>L</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>M</td>
                <td>J</td>
                <td>V</td>
                <td>S</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><p class="letra">A</p><p class="numero">1</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">B</p><p class="numero">2</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">C</p><p class="numero">3</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">D</p><p class="numero">4</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">E</p><p class="numero">5</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="letra">F</p><p class="numero">6</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">G</p><p class="numero">7</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">H</p><p class="numero">8</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">I</p><p class="numero">9</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">A</p><p class="numero">10</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">B</p><p class="numero">11</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">C</p><p class="numero">12</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="letra">A</p><p class="numero">13</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">E</p><p class="numero">14</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">F</p><p class="numero">15</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">G</p><p class="numero">16</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">H</p><p class="numero">17</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">I</p><p class="numero">18</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">A</p><p class="numero">19</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="letra">B</p><p class="numero">20</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">C</p><p class="numero">21</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">D</p><p class="numero">22</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">E</p><p class="numero">23</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">F</p><p class="numero">24</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">G</p><p class="numero">25</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">H</p><p class="numero">26</p></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><p class="letra">I</p><p class="numero">27</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">A</p><p class="numero">28</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">B</p><p class="numero">29</p></td>
                <td><p class="letra">C</p><p class="numero">30</p></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Sírvanse de ver la tabla en pantalla completa porque sino se superponen los elementos.

Me terminé dando cuenta que era por la cantidad de dígitos en los números. Por alguna razón el posicionamiento se ve afectado por el contenido del elemento.

Traté de solucionarlo poniendo un espacio a la derecha del número (los que son de un solo dígito) en el `HTML` pero no cambiaba nada. Le puse entonces un guion bajo y aunque cambió, ese caracter se colocaba tan junto del número que seguía haciendo que el posicionamiento descentrara las letras y los números.

A lo último le puse un numero cualquiera a la derecha (por ejemplo a E5 le puse E56, a E9 le puse E91, etc., y eso sí funcionó.

> Pero ahora, ¿cómo podría hacer para solucionar ese problema de alineación dejando los números con un solo dígito (no teniendo que poner 01, 02, 03...) y sin tener que configurar para esos números un valor distinto de posicionamiento?. Aclaración: no busco centrar los elementos en el medio de las celdas, sino alinearlos en posición en donde están.

Comment: No entiendo dices "no busco centrar los elementos en el medio de las celdas, sino alinearlos en posición en donde están", pero ya están donde están :S

Comment: que necesidad tienes de duplicar las preguntas, ya has realizado ayer la pregunta. Tienes que preguntarte porque talvez no tuvo la atencion deseasa.. tal vez es poco clara. Podrias agregar imagenes de como lo tienes vs como lo quieres.  Lectura recomendada [ask] y [tour]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Alinear elementos dentro de una tabla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/577060/alinear-elementos-dentro-de-una-tabla)

Comment: Pues si disminuyes el tamaño de las letras se arreglaría?...

Comment: Bueno... puede ser que me cueste explicarme ya que soy nuevo en esto (tanto en la página como el la programación), pero si le cambié el hecho de que se pueda ejecutar el código para visualizar la tabla y algún otra aclaración que por lo que veo generó más confusión. No es mi intención generar contenido duplicado, por eso iba a tratar de borrar la pregunta anterior porque consideraba que esta estaba mejor hecha y además porque no tuvo una respuesta que me sirva.

Comment: En sí, no soy de saber cómo es que se utilizan los foros en general (sé que tienen sus instrucciones pero igual uno se termina "mandando" porque por ahí con las correcciones uno termina entendiendo mejor que con las instrucciones. La verdad es que no sé si al no recibir respuesta en un día, una hora o lo que sea, la pregunta queda "enterrada" por otras nuevas. No sé si ustedes vieron las preguntas que hice porque aparecen en algún lugar de "recientes", pero igual no tengo intención de repetir esto de borrar y rehacer las preguntas, era más que nada para tratar de "emprolijar" la que hice ayer.

Comment: @Yussef      Lo que quiero decir es que no quiero que vayan al centro de la celda. Justamente les aplique a cada Párrafo -dentro de los TD- la propiedad Position con el valor Relative y las propiedades Left y Top con los valores ahí indicados, para que queden en esa ubicación dentro de la celda. Lo que pasa es que por alguna razón las celdas que tienen para el número el elemento Párrafo con UN solo dígito, hacen que las letras se vean como "movidas" más a la derecha que las que tienen dos dígitos (que son mayoría). ---->continúa

Comment: ---> Y para el caso de los números, si comparas por ejemplo las casillas E5 y C12, se ve que la letra E parece más corrida a la derecha con respecto a C (y a las otras de las casillas de abajo), sin embargo el número (5) parece centrado con el número (12) de la casilla de abajo: está entre medio del 1 y el 2. Así es como quiero que queden los números. Pero por alguna razón el número (9) de la casilla I9 no se centra como los otros números de un solo dígito. Y las letras de las casillas A1, B2, C3, D4, E5, F6, G7, H8, I9, se muevan un poco a la izquierda para quedar en la misma línea q as otras

Comment: Pero con una configuración única, no teniendo que poner valores diferentes para las casillas que tienen números de un solo dígito. Si es que hay manera.

Comment: Cris223511.dev   No creo, porque supongo que cambiaría la proporción pero igual seguirían desalineadas. Lo único que se me ocurre es hacer una clase específica para esas casillas y cambiarle los valores de Top y Left, pero lo veo cómo algo engorroso. La idea era hacer una configuración única para los <p> que tenían letras y para los <p> que tenían números,.

Comment: Ten presente que [es.so] _no es un foro_. Y no es que las preguntas "se pisen" o no por otras: a veces consigues respuestas en horas, otras en días, semanas, meses... No es inmediatez lo que se busca aquí, sino preguntas y respuestas _de calidad_ que sean de provecho tanto para los autores de las mismas como para otros que lleguen a tener un problema similar. De hecho, esta pregunta es casi casi un clon de la pregunta anterior. Borra esta (o aquella). Por último, pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta, y agrega los detalles que consideres pertinentes (o que te hayan solicitado).

Comment: No tengo problema en ayudarte y creo poder dejar las letras y número donde sea, pero el problema es que no entiendo cómo quieres que quede. Te recomiendo que armes un dibujo y lo coloques

Comment: Ahí lo hice. No es que hayan quedado (letras y números) perfectamente alineados pero... al ojo humano, estoy conforma y además ya me cansé. No sé si pasándolo por acá como respuesta se podrá ejecutar para ver cómo quedó.

Comment: @Ezequiel pues disminuyendo el tamaño de las letras y alinearlas al centro, repasa un poco sobre flex y position, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

```css
    table {border: solid; width: 660.500px; margin-left: 25%; margin-top: 30px; text-align: center; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: white;}

td, th {border: solid; padding: 0; height: 45px;}

th {background-color: grey;}

td {  vertical-align: middle;}


.sinBordes td{ /* Nueva clase */
  border: none; /* Mismo estilo */
}

.letra{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: -15px;
    top: -4px;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-weight: 700;
 }

 .numero{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 15px;
    top: 5px;
    font-size: 22px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: 
 }

 .casillasconI{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 8.2px;
    top: 0px;
    font-size: 22px;
 }
```

```html
<table>
        <th colspan="7"><span style="font-size: 1.2em;">Farmacias de Turno</span><br>Noviembre 2022</th>
        <tr style="background-color: black; color: white;" class="sinBordes">
            <td>D</td>
            <td>L</td>
            <td>M</td>
            <td>M</td>
            <td>J</td>
            <td>V</td>
            <td>S</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td><p class="letra">A&nbsp;</p><p class="numero">1</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">B&nbsp;</p><p class="numero">2</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">C&nbsp;</p><p class="numero">3</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">D&nbsp;</p><p class="numero">4</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">E&nbsp;</p><p class="numero">5</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p class="letra">F&nbsp;</p><p class="numero">6</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">G&nbsp;</p><p class="numero">7</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">H&nbsp;</p><p class="numero">8</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">I&nbsp;</p><p class="numero"><span class="casillasconI">9</span></p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">A</p><p class="numero">10</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">B</p><p class="numero">11</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">C</p><p class="numero">12</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p class="letra">A</p><p class="numero">13</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">E</p><p class="numero">14</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">F</p><p class="numero">15</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">G</p><p class="numero">16</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">H</p><p class="numero">17</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">I</p><p class="numero"><span class="casillasconI">18</span></p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">A</p><p class="numero">19</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p class="letra">B</p><p class="numero">20</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">C</p><p class="numero">21</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">D</p><p class="numero">22</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">E</p><p class="numero">23</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">F</p><p class="numero">24</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">G</p><p class="numero">25</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">H</p><p class="numero">26</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><p class="letra">I</p><p class="numero"><span class="casillasconI">27</span></p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">A</p><p class="numero">28</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">B</p><p class="numero">29</p></td>
            <td><p class="letra">C</p><p class="numero">30</p></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).